# Getting error while reading unicode file in C

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, glibc, gio

I want to read a unicode file in C (Cygwin/GCC) using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>


void split_parse(char* text){
    char** res = g_strsplit(text, "=", 2);
    printf("Key = %s : ", res[0]);
    printf("Value = %s", res[1]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setenv ("CYGWIN", "nodosfilewarning", 1);

    GIOChannel *channel;
    GError *err = NULL;
    int reading = 0;
    const gchar* enc;
    guchar magic[2] = { 0 };
    gsize bytes_read = 0;

    const char* filename = "C:\\CONFIG";


    channel = g_io_channel_new_file (filename, "r", &err);

    if (!channel) {
        g_print("%s", err->message);
        return 1;
    }

    if (g_io_channel_set_encoding(channel, NULL, &err) != G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL) {
        g_print("g_io_channel_set_encoding: %s\n", err->message);
        return 1;
    }

    if (g_io_channel_read_chars(channel, (gchar*) magic, 2, &bytes_read, &err) != G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL) {
        g_print("g_io_channel_read_chars: %s\n", err->message);
        return 1;
    }

    if (magic[0] == 0xFF && magic[1] == 0xFE)
    {
        enc = "UTF-16LE";
    }
    else if (magic[0] == 0xFE && magic[1] == 0xFF)
    {
        enc = "UTF-16BE";
    }
    else
    {
        enc = "UTF-8";
        if (g_io_channel_seek_position(channel, 0, G_SEEK_CUR, &err) == G_IO_STATUS_ERROR)
        {
            g_print("g_io_channel_seek: failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (g_io_channel_set_encoding (channel, enc, &err) != G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL) {
        g_print("%s", err->message);
        return 1;
    }

    reading = 1;
    GIOStatus status;
    char* str = NULL;
    size_t len;

    while(reading){

        status = g_io_channel_read_line(channel, &str, &len, NULL, &err);
        switch(status){
            case G_IO_STATUS_EOF:
                reading = 0;
                break;
            case G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL:
                if(len == 0) continue;
                split_parse(str);
                break;
            case G_IO_STATUS_AGAIN: continue;
            case G_IO_STATUS_ERROR:
            default:
                //throw error;
                reading = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    g_free(str);
    g_io_channel_unref(channel);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The file (C:\CONFIG) content is as follows:

```
h-debug="1"
name=ME
ÃÆÿÐ®©=2¾1¼
```

While reading it I am always getting the following error message at "g_io_channel_read_line" inside the while loop:

> 0x800474f8 "Invalid byte sequence in conversion input"

What am I doing wrong? How to read a file like this in C using glib?

**EDIT: Hexdump of the file**

[image]

Comment: Your text file may/may not include the initial BOM (byte order mark).  Show a hex dump of the first 10 bytes or so of the text file.  BTW, other encodings exist other than the 3 coded.  GTG

Comment: @chux hexdump of the file added.

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains the 3-byte UTF8 BOM of (EF BB BF).   byte-order-mark.

Your code defaults to UTF8, but does not consume the BOM.

```
channel, 0, G_SEEK_CUR, &err
```

s/b

```
channel, 3, G_SEEK_CUR, &err
```

Further, I would recommend extending your `magic` code to read 4 bytes and affirmatively discern the BOM.

*If* you do not find a BOM, you could assume encoding NULL which I think is binary.  Or throw an error Or fix the wayward text file Or, if your are pedantic, sequentially try all known encoding types.

---

UTF32BE              "\x00\x00\xFE\xFF"
UTF32LE              "\xFF\xFE\x00\x00"
UTF8                 "\xEF\xBB\xBF"
UTF16BE              "\xFE\xFF"
UTF16LE              "\xFF\xFE"
NULL for binary